# How to update jQuery Progress bar according to a value at the session variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I need to fill the progress bar according to the current value of a session variable. The value will be not be constant and is increasing.
How to make it load by itself?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 80
        });
    });
    </script>
 <div class="demo">

<div id="progressbar"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP

```
...
// disable caching
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1991 05:00:00 GMT');  // disable IE caching
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

echo progressbar_value;
exit();
...
```

JS

```
var refresh_period = 1000; // ms
var script_path = '/script.php';

function updateProgressBar () {
    $.ajax({url: script_path,  success: function (value) {
       $('#progressbar').progressbar(value);
       if (data.value == 100) {
          clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }
}
var interval = setInterval('updateProgressBar()', refresh_period);
```

Comment: You don't have data object in the javascript example. Correct code is: if (value == 100) {

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use AJAX to talk to a PHP file that echos the session var. It can then update the progress bar.

Comment: How can I do that? I am somehow new to client side development!

Comment: But how can I make the method which updates the filling of the bar runs every now and then to fill the bar?

Comment: You can have it call that ajax method every N seconds. On success, it then updates the progress bar. You can use setTimeout.

Comment: Remember that if another tab/window (or even ajax connection within the same window) is doing an action on the server, especially a long one which you want the progress bar for, it will most likely have locked the session file, preventing your progress update handler from working. Make sure you `session_write_close()` in the long-running page before trying to do any kind of "how far have things gone" update query.